# Require Help for Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I am Doing a Check on the JTextfield Values that it Should be **XX.YY.Z** format

**`10.01.5`**

No space at beginning or after allowed.

**EDIT:-**

How Can I Specify Last as Alphanumeric character i.e. **Z** can be Number or character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d` matches a digit, and `\.` matches a dot.

```
\d\d\.\d\d\.\d
```

i.e. `"\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\.\\d"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience in Java but this what I would do in PHP.

```
^\d\d.\d\d.\d$
```

**\d** represents one degit, **\d\d** represents two degits

**^** a caret character is there to ensure that it must start with the number (No spaces at the beginning)

**$** a dollar sign ensures that there will be no spaces or other characters at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use quantifiers

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d
```

That is the indicated, and your regex becomes more easy to read and to change.

more on [Quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Comment: The {1} quantifier is useless.